# Generate variable names in loop

Tags: python, variables, attributes

Is it possible to generate names of variables in loop?

The simple situation:

```
class product():
    self.shop1_name = None
    self.shop1_price = None
    self.shop2_name = None 
    self.shop2_price = None 
    ...

p = product()

# shops is a list of shops
for i, shop in enumerate(shops[0:5]):
    p.shop+i+1_name = shop.name # so shop1_name in first loop, shop2_name in second etc...
    p.shop+i+1_price = shop.price
```

So there is many attributes `shop1_price, shop2_price...shop10_price` and I want to fill them in one loop not to have write all of these by hand.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Yes.  You can dynamically add attributes to an object using the `setattr` builtin.  Do you actually *want* to do that?  [Probably not](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).  Rather than having:

`shop1_name, shop2_name, ...` why not have a list?

```
shop_names = [...]
```

---

Better yet, since the shops seem to have lots of data associated with them (`name`, `price`, ...), you could have a structured (or unstructured) record type to represent the shop and then have a list of shops.  Examples of the record type could be as simple as a `dict` or `collections.namedtuple`, or you could add a light-weight class to hold the shop data:

```
class Shop(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

shops = [Shop('name1', 100), Shop('name2', 200), ...]
```

Now, rather than `shop1_name`, you have `shops[0].name` (which really isn't too different) plus you pick up the ability to iterate over all your shops as a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use dictionaries or lists?

```
Shop = [{'name': "Nisa Local", 'price': 5000},{'name': "Tescos", 'price': 800000}]
```

To add a shop use:

```
Shop.append({'name': "Asda", 'price': 10000})
```

or just lists:

```
ShopNames = ['Nisa Local', 'Tescos']
ShopPrices = [5000, 800000]
```

and to add use tyhis:

```
ShopNames.append('Asda')
ShopPrices.append(10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a data structure like a dict:

```
class product():
self.shops = [ {'name': None, 'price': None}, ... ]
...

p = product()

# shops is a list of shops
for i, shop in enumerate(shops[0:5]):
    p.shops[i]['name'] = shop.name 
    p.shops[i]['price'] = shop.price
```

Comment: `shop.name` won't work the way it would in Javascript.  `shop['name']` would though.